# Update moodle 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: moodle

When upgrading from moodle 2.6 to 2.7 error occurs. We see a white screen. The version of PHP and MySQL comply with the requirements. If install the moodle 2.7, everything works. Problems when trying to update.
MySQL tip table - InnoDb

Comment: First of all find in your web server log errors, that appear when you try to open a moodle page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed any additional themes or plugins? Its probably one of those, put this inside `config.php` to show any errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

There are also some upgrade notes here - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Upgrading#Check_for_plugin_updates

Comment: the error occurred:    Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in ...\cache\stores\memcache\lib.php on line 138

Comment: in this line lib.php (138) - $this->connection = new Memcache;

Comment: Problem solved after switching module memcache in php on the system